# Command history for class instances

Tags: python, class, methods, decorator, history

I want to create a decorator class `AddToHistory` to modify history entries of other classes instances when a certain method got called.
So, for example, in pseudo code:

```
class AddToHistory(object):
    ...
    def __call__(self, ...):
        instance.history.append(fun_name)


class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.history = []

    @AddToHistory
    def methodA():
        ...

    @AddToHistory
    def methodB(input):
        ...

    def methodC():
        ...


inst = MyClass()
print(inst.history)
>>> []

inst.methodA()
print(inst.history)
>>> ['methodA']

inst.methodB(myinput)
print(inst.history)
>>> ['methodA', 'methodB']

inst.methodC()
print(inst.history)
>>> ['methodA', 'methodB']
```

The decorator should automatically use the name of the decorated method.

I already searched and tried for quite some time but couldn't find a good way to implement this. 
Any hints from your side?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a decorator function instead but you can turn it into a decorator class if you really insist (but unless you want a parameterized decorator there's not good reason for a decorator class here):

```
from functools import wraps

def add_to_history(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kw):
        self.history.append(func.__name__)
        return func(self, *args, **kw)
    return wrapper

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.history = []

    @add_to_history
    def methodA(self):
        return "method A"

    @add_to_history
    def methodB(self, input):
        return "method B %s" % input

    def methodC(self):
        return "methodC"



inst = MyClass()
print(inst.history)

inst.methodA()
print(inst.history)

inst.methodB("myinput")
print(inst.history)

inst.methodC()
print(inst.history)
```

Comment: Nice, that's it :-)
Thank you!